# Space between youtube embed link and an image - I can't seem where it is coming from?

Tags: html, css

So I have an HTML page with some JS.

I have an embedded YT video inserted with iframe and a regular image below it. Between them there's some space which isn't coming from neither of the iframe nor from the image. (I tried to select it using inspect tools and it seems to be from the parent element).

Here's a screenshot to see what I'm talking about:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swot0.png)

Here's the code:

```css
*reset.css*

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video, button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


*main.css*
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    src: url("../fonts/Proxima\ Nova\ Bold.woff");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova Thin';
    src: url("../fonts/Proxima\ Nova\ Thin.woff");
}

body {
    background-color: #00558c;
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif !important;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    background-color: #0b101a !important;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container-site {
    background-color: #0b101a !important;
}

.nav-index {
    height: 100%;
}

.custom-color {
    color: #FF7700 !important;
}

.nav-link {
    font-size: 1.4rem !important;
}

.navbar-custom {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.logo-carabella {
    width: 9rem;
}

.logo-erasmus {
    width: 9rem;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}

.welcome-index {
    height: 47rem;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 2.5rem 2.5rem;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 2.5rem 2.5rem;
    border-radius: 0 0 2.5rem 2.5rem;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
    background-color: #0b101a;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #FF7700;
    width: 10px;
}

.jumbotron-custom {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: #fff;
}

.lead-font {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova Thin', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif !important;
}

.jumbotron-fluid {
    z-index: 9999;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.container-text-robot {
    padding-top: 8rem;
}

.index-modificat-2 {
    z-index: 1;
    top: 20;
}

.index-modificat {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.video-prezentare {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.text-robot-1 {
    width: 47rem;
}

.text-robot-2 {
    width: 34rem;
}

.circuit-video {
    width: 1024px;
}

#video-changer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}

.hard-drive {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -600px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.cd-video {
    width: 65%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3%;
    right: -405px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.slider-hard {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4%;
    right: -590px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.sageata-change {
        width: 2.5%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -60%;
        right: -592px;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        z-index: 3;
        cursor: pointer;
}

.sageata-change-stanga {
    width: 2.5%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -60%;
    right: -23px;
    z-index: 3;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container-site-fara-nav {
    width: 1366px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.instructor-sageti {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 35%;
    width: 20rem;
}

.rotate-back {
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 }
 
 .rotate-fwd {
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 }

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        margin-left: 2rem;
    }
    .navbar-custom {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translatex(-50%);
    }
    .navbar-custom > li {
        margin: 0 4rem;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .logo-carabella {
        display: none;
    }
    .logo-erasmus {
        display: none;
    }
    .nav-link {
        font-size: 1rem !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
    .navbar-custom > li {
        margin: 0 2rem;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 940px) {
    .navbar-custom > li {
        margin: 0 1rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Made4Europe</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container-site">
        <section class="nav-index">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo-carabella"></a>
                  <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-custom mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                      <a class="nav-link custom-color" href="#">Acasa<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link custom-color" href="#">Lectii</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link custom-color" href="#">Teste</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link custom-color" href="#">Detalii</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img src="img/logo-erasmus.png" class="logo-erasmus"></a>
                        </div>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </nav>
        </section>
        <div class="container-site-fara-nav">
        <section class="welcome-index">
            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbotron-custom text-center">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="container-text-robot">
                    <img src="img/text.png" class="text-robot-1"/>
                    <img src="img/text 2.png" class="text-robot-2"/>
                  <object data="svg/Robot 1.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="index-modificat"></object>               
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="video-prezentare">
          <iframe width="1024" height="768" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4OH3JZyLVJE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          <div id="wrapper-video-circuit">
            <img src="img/video.png" class="circuit-video">
          </div>
          <div id="video-changer">
            <img src="img/hard-drive.png" class="hard-drive">
            <img src="img/cd.png" class="cd-video">
            <img src="img/slider-hard.png" class="slider-hard">
            <img src="img/sageata.png" class="sageata-change">
            <img src="img/sageata.png" class="sageata-change-stanga">
            <img src="img/instructor.png" class="instructor-sageti">
          </div>
        </section>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Where does that space come from? I thought it might be the image, but it's not. It has no space in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `.video-prezentare` a `line-height: 0;`.

```
.video-prezentare {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: That was right. I will accept the answer asap. Can you explain why should does it work?

Comment: You've got a generic `line-height: 1;` set on the `body`, and that's applied to all elements. Even though there isn't any text in the `video-prezentare` div, it's `line-height` property still plays a minor role in the spacing between elements. Setting `line-height: 0;` removes any whitespace that was unintentionally being added by the generic `line-height: 1` that is set on `body`. Hope that helps!